#  INNER JOIN Join expression not supported?

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I have a problem with the following SQL query:

```
select 
    [customer].teskilat_kodu, [customer].hesab_nomresi,
    [customer].soyad, [customer].ad, [customer].ataadi, [customer].unvan,
    [customer].tevellud, [customer].nomre, [customer].cins, [customer].status,
    [customer].qohum_nomresi, [customer].email 
from 
    [customer] 
INNER JOIN 
    [kart_novleri] ON [kart_novleri].id = '[customer].kart_novu'  
ORDER BY 
    [customer].id ASC
```

It returns the error:

> Error: Join expression not supported

Comment: Don't put your JOIN condition into single quotes! Use this instead: `..... ON [kart_novleri].id = [customer].kart_novu` (note: **no quotes** around the `[customer].kart_novu` !)

Comment: Why do you need the char:  '  here '[customer].kart_novu' ?

Comment: I have need '' because [kart_novleri].id int and [customer].kart_novu String tpye.

Comment: You cannot join an INT to a STRING - those types need to be identical (or you need to explicitly **convert** one of the values to the other type - but that's **really bad practice**). So really: **WHY** is your JOIN on two columns of different types?? That's a **BIG** design smell !

Comment: 1) How is that related to C#? 2) Which SQL server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In access (untested):

```
select 
    [customer].teskilat_kodu, [customer].hesab_nomresi,
    [customer].soyad, [customer].ad, [customer].ataadi, [customer].unvan,
    [customer].tevellud, [customer].nomre, [customer].cins, [customer].status,
    [customer].qohum_nomresi, [customer].email 
from 
    [customer] 
INNER JOIN 
    [kart_novleri] ON [kart_novleri].id = CInt([customer].kart_novu)
ORDER BY 
    [customer].id ASC
```

In TSQL something like this should work:

```
select 
    [customer].teskilat_kodu, [customer].hesab_nomresi,
    [customer].soyad, [customer].ad, [customer].ataadi, [customer].unvan,
    [customer].tevellud, [customer].nomre, [customer].cins, [customer].status,
    [customer].qohum_nomresi, [customer].email 
from 
    [customer] 
INNER JOIN 
    [kart_novleri] ON cast([kart_novleri].id as varchar(max)) = [customer].kart_novu 
ORDER BY 
    [customer].id ASC
```

or this

```
select 
    [customer].teskilat_kodu, [customer].hesab_nomresi,
    [customer].soyad, [customer].ad, [customer].ataadi, [customer].unvan,
    [customer].tevellud, [customer].nomre, [customer].cins, [customer].status,
    [customer].qohum_nomresi, [customer].email 
from 
    [customer] 
INNER JOIN 
    [kart_novleri] ON [kart_novleri].id = cast([customer].kart_novu as int)
ORDER BY 
    [customer].id ASC
```

Depending on your data you may want to do "isnumber" on the results of the cast before the join to avoid fatal errors.  I'd suggest using a CTE to "massage" the column before the join to ensure robustness -- OR **store the original value as an int!**

Comment: CodeInChaos  my database access    .mdb

Comment: I believe you use CInt to cast to an integer in Acess

Comment: `CINT()` is cast to `SMALLINT`, `CLNG()` is cast to `INTEGER` ('long integer'), the wacky world of Access ;)